# Couldn't run ensime on Play 2.3 project

Tags: scala, emacs, playframework, ensime

I'm new to Emacs.

I've installed ensime using `M-x package-install` and then `ensime`.

By executing `ensime` command in Emacs and giving the project path (which `gen-ensime` is executed on it) I get the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "check that sbt is on your PATH and that your config is compatible with http://github.com/ensime/ensime-server/wiki/Example-Configuration-File [(wrong-type-argument stringp nil)]")
  signal(error ("check that sbt is on your PATH and that your config is compatible with http://github.com/ensime/ensime-server/wiki/Example-Configuration-File [(wrong-type-argument stringp nil)]"))
  error("check that sbt is on your PATH and that your config is compatible with http://github.com/ensime/ensime-server/wiki/Example-Configuration-File [(wrong-type-argument stringp nil)]")
  (condition-case ex (ensime--1) ((quote error) (error (format "check that sbt is on your PATH and that your config is compatible with %s [%s]" "http://github.com/ensime/ensime-server/wiki/Example-Configuration-File" ex))))
  ensime()
  call-interactively(ensime record nil)
  command-execute(ensime record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "ensime")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
```

SBT 0.13.6 is added to path and when I type `ensime-sbt-command` and `C-j` in Lisp-Interaction window it shows the SBT path.

My project SBT version is 0.13.5, Scala 2.11.1, Play 2.3.3, ensime-sbt 0.1.5-SNAPSHOT.

Emacs version is 24, ensime version is 20141101.910.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am struggling with the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I gave the folder path instead of .ensime file path. That was the problem which is solved.

[More info](https://github.com/ensime/ensime-server/issues/693)